# Using self join in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, outer-join

How can I create the below JOIN in Postgres , This code is from Oracle and it has one join condition which I am not familiar with.

```
T3.u_ffm_sub_id(+) = T3.u_ffm_id(+)
```

It is like self join but (+) is on both the sides of condition, So I am confused how to create same in postgres.

Below is the complete code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   CASE
       WHEN MD.u_ffm_id = MD.u_ffm_sub_id THEN MD.patient
       ELSE T3.patient
   END
INTO lRet
FROM UPI.memdate MD,
   UPI.memdate T3
WHERE T3.hmo           = pHmo
AND T3.u_ffm_sub_id(+) = T3.u_ffm_id(+)
AND MD.hmo             = T3.HMO(+)
AND MD.u_ffm_sub_id    = T3.u_ffm_sub_id(+)
AND md.patient         = pPatient;
```

Comment: That's Oracle's proprietary (deprecated) way of writing an outer join

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 2):

These are outer joins, and they are easy to translate to standard conforming SQL.

1. If the `(+)` is on the right side:

   ```
   FROM a, b
   WHERE a.x = b.y(+)
   ```

   gets translated to

   ```
   FROM a LEFT JOIN b
      ON a.x = b.y
   ```
2. If the `(+)` is on the other side, it would be a `RIGHT JOIN`.
3. If the `(+)` is on both sides:

   ```
   FROM a, b
   WHERE a.x(+) = b.y(+)
   ```

   gets translated to

   ```
   FROM a FULL JOIN b
      OM a.x = b.y
   ```